# Reactjs Material UI Table component causes grid to expand

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui

I have a Table component that is nested in a Grid component and I would like the Grid component to remain in its width when my Table component is rendered. My current code causes the Grid component to expand but I'm not sure how to prevent this? I'm pretty stuck :/

Before rendering the Table component when it has not received data:
[image: Before Table i]

After rendering the Table component when it received data:
[image]
Here are my codes from parent to child

Mainpage

```
    return (
        <Box>
            <Box sx={{display: "grid", alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center", paddingTop: "40px"}}>
                <Typography variant="h4">Some Header</Typography>
            </Box>
            <Box sx={{display: "grid", alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center", paddingTop: "30px"}}>
                <Wallet></Wallet>
            </Box>
            <Box sx={{display: "grid", alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center", paddingTop: "40px"}}>
                <Typography variant="h5">Some Other Header</Typography>
            </Box>
            <Box sx={{display: "grid", alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center", paddingTop: "10px"}}>
                <Cmc></Cmc>
            </Box>
            
        </Box>
    )
```

Wallet

```
return (
        <Box>
            <Grid container rowSpacing={2} sx={{paddingInline: "25px"}} width={"100%"}>
                <Grid item xs={12}>
                    <Queryfield text={fields.staking} onFunction={getStakingAmounts}/>
                    <Stakingfield resData={resData.stakingRes}/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12}>
                    <Queryfield text={fields.outstandingWithdrawals} onFunction={getOutstandingWithdrawals}/>
                    <Outstandingfield/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12}>
                    <Queryfield text={fields.withdrawnAmounts} onFunction={getWithdrawnAmount}/>
                    <Withdrawnfield/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Box>
    )
```

Queryfield

```
    return (
        <Box>
            <Typography sx={{ paddingLeft: "0px" }}>{txt}</Typography>
            <Box sx={{display: "inline-flex", width: "100%"}}>
                <TextField onChange={handleQueryChange} label="Enter Address" fullWidth type="search" variant="filled" size="small" />
                <Button variant="outlined" onClick={handleQuery}>Send</Button>
            </Box>
        </Box>
    )
```

Stakingfield

```
    const renderTable = () => {
        if (stakingRes !== "") {
            return (
                <TableContainer component={Paper}>
                <Table size="small">
                    <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell>Validator Address</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>Delegated Amount</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>Token</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>Shares</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                    <TableBody>
                        {stakingRes.map((row, index) => (
                            <TableRow key={index}>
                                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">{row.validatorAddress}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>{Number(row.delegatedAmount) / 10**18}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>{row.denom}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>{Number(row.shares) / 10**18}</TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                        ))}
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            </TableContainer>
            );
        }
        else {
            return (
                <div></div>
            )
        }
    }

    return (
        <Box>
            {renderTable()}
        </Box>
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue.

For anyone wondering, the Table component in Material UI is not responsive. I used a DataGrid and it all worked out.